# Realtime Prediction.io with Apache Storm

Tags: java, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, apache-storm, predictionio

I want to implement a music recommendation system that can generate recommended music playlists in realtime. I believe that this can be implemented in Prediction.io...

However, due to Prediction.io's design, I need to call pio train, pio deploy, in order to update the learning model with the new actions done by the user (like music, etc.) Hence, I would need to run these commands every 2 hours (or another appropriate time interval).

I recently came across Apache Storm, and I really like the concept of a "realtime hadoop" processing. Hence, I was thinking if I can incorporate Prediction.io with Apache Storm, so that the learning is done "online", which will allow my app to recommend music within a few likes/actions by the user, instead of having the user wait until the learning model is updated.

If this is not viable, then is it possible to incorporate Spark's Mllib into a Apache Storm bolt (java), since I can build recommendation systems with it (and it also seems that Prediction.io itself is built upon Apache Spark)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The use case seems viable, but I would not consider 'need to run something every few hours' as a good motivation for using storm. On the other hand, if your learning data is 'streaming', you can model your storm topology to update its internal knowledge base every time new data arrives. This will allow you to use the most updated knowledge base every time user queries something.

As to which libraries can be used with Storm, any java library (in fact any library in any language if it can interface with java) should work.